# Is there a way to make a Checkbox on/off in Visual Studio C# by retrieving a MySqlDataReader boolean value?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, type-conversion, boolean

new to Stack Overflow here.
I'm searching for a way to make my CheckBox1 to go on and off as I click it, without the need for a label or .Text because in my MySQL data the corresponding value is a boolean.

When I list my data in a gridview in another page, the value remains locked and displays as I hope, but in my another CRUD page my checkbox isn't properly configured.

I'm struggling to find a way to link the CheckBox1.Checked to corresponding tinyint value in visual studio.

The checkbox displays a label value as True or False, and I don't know yet how to make such value to tick my checkbox, and if this is the right way to think about the code. I apologize if I wasn't clear enough.

I have displayed below the html object, an attempt to retrive the boolean directly to the checkbox, and the actual read method so I could try to get the proper reading of CheckBox1.

```
ativo:<asp:Checkbox id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Text=" " TextAlign="Left"></asp:Checkbox><br />
```

```cs
String sql = String.Format("insert into cliente(codigo, nome, email, telefone, senha, ativo) values('{0}','{1}',{2},{3},{4},'{5}')", txtCodigo.Text, txtNome.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtTelefone.Text, txtSenha.Text, (Checkbox1.Checked ? 1 : 0));

protected void read(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection(sc);
                conexao.Open();
                String sql = "select * from cliente where codigo={0}" + txtCodigo.Text;
                sql = String.Format(sql, txtCodigo.Text);
                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexao);
                MySqlDataReader registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
                if (registro.Read())
                {
                    txtCodigo.Text = registro["codigo"].ToString();
                    txtNome.Text = registro["nome"].ToString();
                    txtEmail.Text = registro["email"].ToString();
                    txtTelefone.Text = registro["telefone"].ToString();
                    txtSenha.Text = registro["senha"].ToString();
                    Checkbox1.Checked.ToString() = registro["ativo"].ToString();
                    lblMensagem.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMensagem.Text = "Registro não encontrado !";
                    limpar();
                }
                conexao.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                lblMensagem.Text = "Ocorreu um erro tente mais tarde !";
            }
        }
```

I would hope to Create, Read, and Update this checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked property is boolean 
so you can convert value to boolean like this :

```
Checkbox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(registro["ativo"])
```